# Project Euler: Name scores - adding together the values of lots of words

Tags: python, text

I'm doing [project Euler #22](https://projecteuler.net/problem=22), which basically requires you to go through a list of names in a .txt file, sort them into alphabetical order and then sum the values of the letters in the name (a=1, b=2 etc) multiplied by the index of each name.

For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.

I've done the following in Python, which gives me the correct value on small list, but the wrong answer on the actual list (which is +5000 names). It seems to overshoot the real answer by a bit.

```
list = ["MARY","PATRICIA"... "ALONSO"]

dictionary = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4, 'E':5, 'F':6, 'G':7, 'H':8, 'I':9, 'J':10, 'K':11, 'L':12, 'M':13, 'N':14, 'O':15, 'P':16, 'Q':17, 'R':18, 'S':19, 'T':20, 'U':21, 'V':22, 'W':23, 'X':24, 'Y':25, 'Z':26}
list.sort()
total = 0
for i in list:
  count = 0
  for j in i:
    count += (dictionary[j])
  else:
    count *= (list.index(i) + 1)
    total += count
print(total)
```

I'm aware that the code is a bit messy (I'm a beginner), but I've been racking my mind but can't think of anything. Can anyone help me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You sum the values of the letters? Cause in your post you're multiplying (in the explanation) and then adding (in the code).

Comment: my bad, meant to add in the example!

Comment: Instead of a dict, you can compute the value of a char with `ord(ch) - ord('A') + 1`. If the names are repeated, `list.index(i) + 1` will be wrong. Try something like `for index, name in enumerate(names, 1):`. Don't use `list` as a variable name, you are hiding the name of a built-in data type.

Comment: Are all the names in uppercase? What would be the value of 'Fred'? or 'FreD'?

Comment: Consider what `index` would return if `L = ['MARY','PATRICIA','MARY']`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using a list comprehension if you want shorter code:

```
li = sorted(["FRED","SUSAN"])
dictionary = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4, 'E':5, 'F':6, 'G':7, 'H':8, 'I':9, 'J':10, 'K':11, 'L':12, 'M':13, 'N':14, 'O':15, 'P':16, 'Q':17, 'R':18, 'S':19, 'T':20, 'U':21, 'V':22, 'W':23, 'X':24, 'Y':25, 'Z':26}
li = sum(i for i in [sum(dictionary[i] for i in li[j])*(j+1) for j in range(len(li))])
print(li)
```

EDIT: sorted() was at the wrong place, corrected

Comment: I don't think you really want to order the characters in a name... Also, the names in the list might be repeated, yet their index is unique.

Comment: Thanks @MarcosModenesi! Edited.

Comment: Closer, but still, this will fail with `li = ['TITO', 'TITO', 'TITO']`.

Comment: Interesting, it yields the correct solution for the Euler Problem though.

Comment: So (in this example with 3 repeated names in the list) the first 'TITO' should be multiplied by 1, the second 'TITO' by 2 and the 3rd 'TITO' by 3? My mistake then. I guess I made some wrong assumptions.

Comment: Yeah that's correct - I didn't realise that list items with the same value are given the same index (i.e. in your case TITO would all have an index of zero I think? I think this is what is giving me the wrong answer.